# Access UI interface started by python application inside docker

Tags: python, opencv, docker, camera, face-recognition

I am using cv2 to access camera of the laptop to take a picture and do face recognition.

I am using python for the same.

I want to ship my code using docker, so I created a docker image of the same.

The problem is:

When I run the code from the native os using `python file.py` (`ubuntu 16.04`), it is working fine as expected and the python is opening a UI to capture an image.

When I am running the same inside docker, I am not having access to the UI interface started by python. Neither I know if the code inside the docker is able to access the camera of the native OS.

My question is, how can I access the UI started by python inside the docker image.